# Process is terminated due to StackOverFlowException when connecting to .mdf database file

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to open a solution that contains an `.mdf` SQL Server database file on a machine that has SQL Server installed, but I get the above error. The exception occurs in the `Settings.Designer`:

```
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\AppDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")]
public string connectionStr 
{
    get 
    {
        return ((string)(this["connectionStr"]));
    }
}
```

[image]

I am able to connect to the database inside of the app with no problem.  However, when I try to run the app, the connection string throws the error above.

[image]

I also attempted connecting the database to an instance of SQL Server and changing the connection string to point to it, and I receive the exact same error message.

As requested, here are the "Copy Details":

> System.StackOverflowException
> HResult=0x800703E9
> Source=
>
> StackTrace:

Comment: What does your named indexer implementation look like? I suspect you're getting a stack overflow because of this.connectionStr -> this["connectionStr"] -> this.connectionStr -> ...

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74454169/edit) your question to include the text and stack trace of the exception, e.g.: from the `Copy Details` that you've screen shotted.

Comment: Can you see anything in the Call Stack window when the exception is thrown?

Comment: This might just be due to a glitch in VS. I'd be tempted to go into the Settings page of the project properties, delete that connection string and then add it back again.

Comment: Your connection string is trying to attach the `.mdf` file to a **LocalDB** instance - does your machine have SQL Server Express **LocalDb** installed? And is it the correct (same) version as where that `.mdf` file was created?